# Find DataTemplate-Generated Elements

Tags: c#, wpf

I m changing TextBlock element's IsEnabled prop of listbox as below

```
    <ListBox Name="myListBox" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myDataTemplate}"
     IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
      <ListBox.ItemsSource>
      <Binding Source="{StaticResource InventoryData}" XPath="Books/Book"/>
      </ListBox.ItemsSource>
   </ListBox>
```

The ListBox uses the following DataTemplate as

```
   <DataTemplate x:Key="myDataTemplate">
      <TextBlock Name="textBlock" FontSize="14" Foreground="Blue">
      <TextBlock.Text>
     <Binding XPath="Title"/>
     </TextBlock.Text>
     </TextBlock>
   </DataTemplate>
```

```
 // Getting the currently selected ListBoxItem
 // Note that the ListBox must have
 // IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem set to True for this to work
   ListBoxItem myListBoxItem =
  (ListBoxItem)(myListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(myListBox.Items.CurrentItem));

 // Getting the ContentPresenter of myListBoxItem
 ContentPresenter myContentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(myListBoxItem);

 // Finding textBlock from the DataTemplate that is set on that ContentPresenter
    DataTemplate myDataTemplate = myContentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
   TextBlock myTextBlock = (TextBlock)myDataTemplate.FindName("textBlock", myContentPresenter);
   // Do something to the DataTemplate-generated TextBlock
   myTextBlock.IsEnabled=false;


   private childItem FindVisualChild<childItem>(DependencyObject obj)
    where childItem : DependencyObject
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
      {
      DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
      if (child != null && child is childItem)
        return (childItem)child;
       else
       {
        childItem childOfChild = FindVisualChild<childItem>(child);
        if (childOfChild != null)
            return childOfChild;
        }
      }
       return null;
   }
```

But How can I set `isEnabled = false;` for all TextBlocks in that listbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply iterate through all the items of list box using a foreach loop and do the same as you are already doing for one item

```
foreach (ListBoxItem item in yourListBox.Items)
        {
        // Getting the ContentPresenter of myListBoxItem
        ContentPresenter myContentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(item );    
        // Finding textBlock from the DataTemplate that is set on that ContentPresenter
        DataTemplate myDataTemplate = myContentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
        TextBlock myTextBlock = (TextBlock)myDataTemplate.FindName("textBlock", myContentPresenter);
        // Do something to the DataTemplate-generated TextBlock
        myTextBlock.IsEnabled=false;
        }
```

**BUT**

this is not the recommended approach to do this. Instead you should use bindings for this purpose

Create a `bool` type property in your `items source` and `bind` the `textbox` `IsEnabled property` with it. When you want to `disable/enable` the textbox simply change that `bool` property and `textbox` will be automatically `enabled or disabled` based on bool value

```
 <TextBlock Name="textBlock" IsEnabled="{Binding path=SomeBoolProperty"} FontSize="14" Foreground="Blue">
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't do that. If there is virtualization the containers for some items will not even be there and you will need to deal with rather messy code to work around that issue. Try to bind `IsEnabled` instead and set the property/XML-attribute accordingly.